# Redirect from non-www to www containing URL

Tags: ubuntu, devops, nginx-config

I have deployed my Next.js 14.x application on a Ubuntu 20 server and am trying to configure Nginx to redirect my site from a non-www URL to a www URL. I want to do this to avoid site duplication and avoid errors when logging in using `Auth0`. The code below does not produce the expected redirect. The server is launched using `pm2` and runs on `localhost:3000` in production mode, after which the site is redirected from `localhost:3000` to the domain.

**domain.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
  }

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl-certs/lapki-certs-key/common-cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl-certs/lapki-certs-key/9172942.key;
            location / {
                # reverse proxy for next server
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

I am a web developer and new to DevOps. I am also afraid to make a mistake because the app is running now globally. Perhaps I made a mistake in the configurations here and am asking for help from people who understand.

Comment: What does this configuration produce?

Comment: If I were you, I would do the reverse. Redirect `www` to non-www. Simple is the best.

Comment: @GeorgiStefkoff now the website working on both domains example.com & www.example.com

Comment: @Raptor I know the reverse redirect is better, but now all SEO is set to "www.*".
I also tested the configuration from the one you suggested and it doesn't redirect correctly. Perhaps the changes in the nginx update are being implemented slowly.

Comment: No. NGINX config changes are applied immediately after a server restart.

Answer (score 1):

@Raptor thanks for the suggestion.
I carefully investigated the answer you suggested and it worked for me. I am sorry for making confuse. Now the code looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl-certs/common-cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl-certs/9172942.key;

        return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
  }

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl-certs/common-cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl-certs/9172942.key;

            location / {
                # reverse proxy for next server
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Comment: Great to hear that the forwarding is now working. Hope this answer can help further audience.